# Cisco ASA Security Contexts: Any Real World Installs?

Tags: security, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

We are looking at deploying a Cisco ASA 5520-I am looking at the [security contexts feature](http://goo.gl/GGLd), and was wondering if anyone has deployed their ASA in this way, and how it is working out for them.

Have you encountered anything that you wished you would have known before you deployed it?

Have you noticed any performance issues?

Is there anybody actually using this feature?

-Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, we use them with contexts (and the ACE modules for Cat65's) and they're great, not easy to use to be honest but they're a powerful piece of kit and I would strongly urge you to get someone on a training course for them before use. They're fast but licensing costs (for the ACEs) can start to rack up if you're pushing a lot of data through them.

We're certainly happy with them, one hint I'd suggest is that you map out your requirements in something like Visio and keep track of everything in a big spreadsheet - it can be easy to lose track of how everything chains together.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that if you do security contexts on your ASA, you lose the ability to terminate a VPN on that appliance.